# Finding the closest element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have the following HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
    <div class="sub_header">
        <input type="text" class="txtBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Using `txtBox` as a starting point, how do I find the closest `content` so I can add something to it?

Here if the full script I have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    var todaysDate = myDate.getDate() + '/' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();

    get_data( todaysDate );

    $(".txtBox").val(todaysDate).datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "+0:+1",
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: "d/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(dateText, obj){
            get_data( $(this), dateText );
        }
    } );

    function get_data( that, dateText ) {

        if ( typeof that != "undefined" )
        {
            that.closest('.main').find('.content').empty().append( dateText );
        }
        else
        {
            $(".content.new").append( dateText ).removeClass('new');
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Updated question with current full script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/etuvoj/1/edit)*

```
$('.txtBox').closest('.main').find('.content').text('Hello oshirowanen!');
```

or:

```
$('.txtBox').closest('div').next('.content').text('Hello oshirowanen!');
```

or:

```
$('.txtBox').parent().next('.content').text('Hello oshirowanen!');
```

Comment: Using your middle example gives the following error `Object doesn't support this property or method`.  The line giving the error looks like this: `that.closest('.main').find('.content').empty().append( dateText );`  where `that` is `.txtBox`.  Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Updated question with current full script.

Comment: For some reason, I can't get your jsbin example to work with the script I have in my original question.

Comment: @oshirowanen great! glad you did it finally!

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to parent of text box which is div and find in siblings of it,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wHRv4/1/)**

```
var content = $('.txtBox').parent().siblings('.content');
```

You can also use the next of parent of text box if the given html has constant structure.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wHRv4/2/)**

```
var content = $('.txtBox').parent().next('.content');
```

Comment: Updated question with current full script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.txtBox').parent().next('.content').html('Whatever')
```

Comment: Updated question with current full script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content').closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
```

this changes the baground clour of the closest div of class .content

Comment: Updated question with current full script.